# join and merge is not return correct number of rows in R

Tags: r, join, merge, dplyr

I have two dataframes which share a common column (named sys_loc_code). The first dataframe (df1) has 1033 rows. The second dataframe (df2) has 2751.

I would like to combine df1 and df2 so get a new dataframe with all columns found in df1 and df2 keeping only rows from df1.

I have tried `join`, `left_join`, and `inner_join` (from `dplyr`) and a simple `merge`. Each of these returns 2057 rows, and I think it should only be returning 1033 to match what is in `df1`. How do I return only rows from df1?

I cannot share the datasets that caused this problem. However, after a bit of consultation, I can recreate the problem with this minimal example:

```
df1 <-
  data.frame(
    sys_loc_code = c("A", "B", "C")
    , df1Val = 1
  )


df2 <-
  data.frame(
    sys_loc_code = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D")
    , df2Val = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1)
  )

left_join(df1, df2)
```

Returns 4 rows while `df1` only has three rows.

Answer (score 0):

The most issue is that `df2$sys_loc_code` contains multiple entries for some of the values in `df1$sys_loc_code`.

`df1$sys_loc_code` has only 3 values, but one of them ("B") is present twice in `df2$sys_loc_code`, meaning those merges will return 4 rows. e.g.

```
left_join(df1, df2)
```

gives

```
  sys_loc_code df1Val df2Val
1            A      1      1
2            B      1      1
3            B      1      2
4            C      1      1
```

So, the short answer to your question may be that the results actually are "correct" based on the code you are writing. If you want something different to happen (e.g., only one entry from `df2` per match), you will likely need to decide exactly what output you want.

For example, if you want the first entry from `df2`:

```
left_join(
  df1
  , df2 %>%
    group_by(sys_loc_code) %>%
    slice(1)
)
```

gives

```
  sys_loc_code df1Val df2Val
1            A      1      1
2            B      1      1
3            C      1      1


left_join(
  df1
  , df2 %>%
    group_by(sys_loc_code) %>%
    summarise(df2Val = mean(df2Val))
)
```

gives

```
  sys_loc_code df1Val df2Val
1            A      1    1.0
2            B      1    1.5
3            C      1    1.0
```

and

```
left_join(
  df1
  , df2 %>%
    mutate(aVarToSortOn = 1:n()) %>%
    group_by(sys_loc_code) %>%
    slice(which.max(aVarToSortOn))
)
```

gives

```
  sys_loc_code df1Val df2Val aVarToSortOn
1            A      1      1            1
2            B      1      2            3
3            C      1      1            4
```

If you know you have unique values in a column, you could also use `filter` to select which match to keep from `df2`

Comment: That is true. 
Am I better off then trying to use a look-up table or something to populate columns found in df2 which I'd like to have in df1?

Comment: It depends on your goal. I would use a `df2 %>% group_by(sys_loc_code)` followed by either `summarise`, `slice`, or `filter` depending on whether you want an aggregate, the first, or a particular entry, then `left_join` in the result.